# Prevent redux-form from destruction/updating

Tags: redux, redux-form

I am using `redux-form` and at some point `destroy` event is fired probably due to some state change, hard to say. I am using `redux-dev-tools` and there, if I eliminate this event, it fixes the behavior of the form. If I look into `trace` (`redux-dev-tools`) section of the `destroy` event it does not show any of my code, so I am having real trouble tracing it down. I am looking for either a way to trace down what is the root reason for the `destroy` event in my code or just prevent all form updates after `Submit` button is hit.

The actual issue is documented here: https://github.com/macarthur-lab/seqr/issues/1334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From these 2 threads:

https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/2982

https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/603#issuecomment-295043224

I figured to supply `destroyOnUnmount: false` property to my `redux form` and it worked. To prevent saving form details when we go away from page and go back, I added `enableReinitialize` parameter also.